# Problem reverting to older Cuda version for TensorFlow in PyCharm (Windows 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

Have been trying to access Cuda within Tensorflow 2.3.1 (through PyCharm) to access my compatible GPU for object detection. TensorFlow was working previously, but when I installed Cuda I realised that it was 11.1 - where TensorFlow has a pre-requisite of Cuda 10.1. I had both versions on my computer, and tried to uninstall all the 11.1 toolkit using the Windows add/remove tool (which is recommended). This seemed to work in removing 11.1, however, when I try to re-install the TensorFlow package into the Project Interpreter Setting (within PyCharm) it comes up with the following error:

> > UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your
> > environment:
> >
> > Specifications:
> >
> > tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|3.7.*']
> >
> > Your python: python=3.8
> >
> > If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for. When python appears to the right, that indicates
> > that the thing on the left is somehow not available for the python
> > version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your
> > python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly
> > specify that.
> >
> > The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
> >
> > feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.1=0
> >
> > Your installed version is: 11.1

EDIT - this the the same when I try to install into the Conda Environment through Anaconda.
System setup:
Windows 10 (64bit)
Tensorflow 2.3.1
Cuda 10.1 (previously 11.1 installed - but I thought **uninstalled**)
cdnn 64_7
Python 3.8
Graphics: 2070Super (driver:456.55)

I understand that PyCharm is unable to install TensorFlow because this has a pre-requisite of Cuda 10.1, but I can't find any references to where it's still pointing to the older (newer 11.1) version. All my path environment variables point to the 10.1 directory. I wonder if there isn't a text/init file somewhere that hard-sets the Cuda version, but haven't found anything on the NVidia site.

Sorry for the noob question, but I am hoping someone can point out where this reference to the newer 11.1 version might be lingering.

Answer (score 0):

So I feel somewhat embarrassed - it turns out despite the Tensorflow website indicating that TensorFlow2.0 was compatible with Python3.8, once I reverted back to an earlier 3.7 it seems to have at least resolved that problem. I was fixated on the fact that it was falsely reporting Cuda v11.1. I think this is now resolved.